# ContextMenuStrip without stealing focus

Tags: c#, winforms

Do you have any idea how to show ContextMenuStrip without stealing focus to current control? I would like to do sort of autocomplete with TextBox and ContextMenuStrip below it as  list of options to choose. But whenever I show ContextMenuStrip it steals focus from textbox so I cannot catch Text_Changed again... I want to use ContextMenuStrip because I want to use pictures, or other other controls in list of given items.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use CMS, it was designed to automatically close when it loses the focus.  Use a ListBox with the DrawMode property set.

Comment: Yes, ended up with this solution...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'cannot  catch Text_Changed' again ? I would imagine something like this should work :

```
// event registered to text box's text changed event
private void HandlerForTextChanged() 
{
  // Get The Current Text So Far Filled In
  // Process and Show Contextmenu strip
  // Reset the focus back to text box (textbox1.SetFocus()) 
}
```

Also, can also think of re-designig the control as one composite control.

Comment: It doesn't work. textbox1.Focus() doesn't provide focus after when a context menu is shown